# Moving a user uploaded image on a shared server

Tags: php

```
<?php
$img1Name = $_FILES['img1']['name'];
$target = 'uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img1']['tmp_name'], $target);
?>
<img src="<?php echo 'uploads/' . $img1Name ?>"/>
```

Why is the image not moving to the uploads folder located where the app is?

Comment: `error_log`? Rights on `$target` folder?

Comment: your target path is wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your target directory is wrong, try using following

```
$target = 'uploads/' .  basename($_FILES["img1"]["name"]);
```